# spark - what is F string for the date/time format?

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Spark document [Datetime Patterns for Formatting and Parsing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) says `F` is about aligned day of week in month but what does it mean?

| Symbol | Meaning | Presentation | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | day-of-week | text | Tue; Tuesday |
| F | aligned day of week in month | number(1) | 3 |

For both `2007-11-10` and `2007-11-11`, it is 2. So it looks it is not about day in a week.

```
spark.sql("select date_format(date '2007-11-10', 'F') AS day_in_week_text").show()

+----------------+
|day_in_week_text|
+----------------+
|               2|
+----------------+
```

```
spark.sql("select date_format(date '2007-11-11', 'F') AS day_in_week_text").show()

+----------------+
|day_in_week_text|
+----------------+
|               2|
+----------------+
```

```
spark.sql("select date_format(date '2007-11-17', 'F') AS day_in_week_text").show()

+----------------+
|day_in_week_text|
+----------------+
|               3|
+----------------+
```

As +7 days increase 1 in the output, I suppose it is number of the week in month. Then what does it mean **aligned day of week in month** exactly?

Comment: Not sure how you got 2 for both `2007-11-10` and `2007-11-11`, it should be respectively 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

From the migration guide [Upgrading from Spark SQL 2.4 to 3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#query-engine):

> In Spark 3.0, datetime pattern letter `F` is **aligned day of week in
> month** that represents the concept of the count of days within the
> period of a week where the weeks are aligned to the start of the
> month. In Spark version 2.4 and earlier, it is **week of month** that
> represents the concept of the count of weeks within the month where
> weeks start on a fixed day-of-week, e.g. `2020-07-30` is 30 days (4
> weeks and 2 days) after the first day of the month, so
> `date_format(date '2020-07-30', 'F')` returns 2 in Spark 3.0, but as a
> week count in Spark 2.x, it returns 5 because it locates in the 5th
> week of July 2020, where week one is 2020-07-01 to 07-04.

---

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")

spark.sql("""
select  date_format(date '2007-11-10', 'F') AS 2007_11_10,
        date_format(date '2007-11-11', 'F') AS 2007_11_11,
        date_format(date '2007-11-17', 'F') AS 2007_11_17
""").show()
#+----------+----------+----------+
#|2007_11_10|2007_11_11|2007_11_17|
#+----------+----------+----------+
#|         3|         4|         3|
#+----------+----------+----------+
```